# gazebo running issues

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way out to run gazebo without dedicated graphics card?? help........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41979/gazebo-running-issues/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo can be run without GUI. Try to write a .world document including the model you need, run roscore, and then rosrun the .world document you have. If you want to use the GUI later, in another terminal run

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzclient
```

But, I highly recommend you to buy a Graphics card for gazebo. It will only cost you about $30 to do this.

---

Originally posted by [lbwdruid](https://answers.ros.org/users/3066/lbwdruid/) with karma: 16 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0